# Meteor router force rerender

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following routs

/product/123

/product/456

the template renders the product data and allows the user to drag things around

when I make a redirect to another product like that

```
Router.go("product",{_id:"456"});
```

the template updates the data but does not re-render the html. that means that what the user dragged stays in place. this is good for some cases but not for mine

the only solution that worked for me was to redirect to another page that sets  clear template and it redirects to the product page

my router function:

```
Router.route('product/:_id/', {
    name:"product",
    data:function(){
      var data =  {product: Products.findOne({_id:objectId(this.params._id)})}
      return data;
    },
    waitOn:function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('Products',this.params._id);
    },
    yieldTemplates: {'product': {to: 'mainArea'}},
});
```

I need a way to tell the router or template to reset the html

Comment: I remember having the same issue with one of my views in the past, but I cannot find it right now. I created a basic [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/73CtXWb28TEBPwEAo/Leaderboard) with a simple yield, and it seems to be working just fine. Can you create a repro based on that? Also, see [this comment](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1337#issuecomment-98835589) on GitHub, it may be related.

Comment: your link to  MeteorPad  does not work

Comment: Strange, I just tested it in incognito and it worked just fine. What are you getting?

Comment: meteor pad logo with loading spiral...

Comment: I tried it with both Chrome and FF and it is working fine. Any clues in the console?

Comment: nope, just lots of posts to http://meteorpad.com/sockjs/647/bd9mx2b5/xhr_send

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81975/discussion-between-masteram-and-zeev-g).

Comment: maybe its a regional issue.. I will try again later

Comment: @ZeevG the MeteorPad problem is almost certainly an SSL problem. It affects users in Israel quite a lot. You can use something like ZenMate to get around the problem. For your own Meteor sites, I recommend using https to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set up an autorun in the template's `onRendered` function that looks for changes to the URL parameters and the resets the template as needed. Something like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {

   var controller = Router.current()
   this.autorun(function() {
      var params = controller.getParams() // Reactive

      // Clear up your drag interface here
   });   
});
```

By accessing `controller.getParams()` (the route controllers reactive parameter list) the outrun will be called when you move between routes on the same template.

Comment: this is good but I dont want to clean the UI manually. I want to make the template re-render as if it is a new one

Comment: OK, but you're fighting the system. The whole point of blaze is to minimise DOM redraws. If the page contents are based on the data context then all those parts of the page will be updated correctly. I don't know your app, but it seems to me that just having the dragging UI relative rendered (or refreshing it manually as above) is the best *Meteor-type* approach.

Comment: OK, I have add the UI reset code to the auto run. hope someone will find a way to reset a template...